# Spark with Scala: write null-like field value in Cassandra instead of TupleValue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, databricks

In one of my collections let's say I have the following field:

```
f: frozen<tuple<text, set<text>>
```

Let's say I want to insert an entry where this particular field is empty, null, non-existent, etc. using a Scala script, where before inserting I map the entry's field like this:

```
sRow("fk") = null // or None, or maybe I simply don't specify the field at all
```

When trying to run the spark script (from Databricks, Spark connector version 1.6) I get the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 133.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 133.0 (TID 447, localhost): com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConversionException: Cannot convert object null to com.datastax.spark.connector.TupleValue.
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(TypeConverter.scala:47)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TypeConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(TypeConverter.scala:43)
```

When using `None` instead of `null` I still get an error, though a different one:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 143.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 143.0 (TID 474, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Expected 2 components, instead of 0
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.types.TupleType.newInstance(TupleType.scala:55)
```

I understand that Cassandra doesn't have the exact notion of null, but I know there's a way of leaving the values out when inserting entries into Cassandra, as I have done this from other environments, like using a nodejs driver for Cassandra.
How can I force a `null`-like value when inserting over an expected TupleValue, or maybe some user defined type?

Answer (score 0):

With modern versions of Cassandra it you can use the "Unbound" feature to have it actually skip nulls. This is probably best for your use case because writing a `null` implicitly writes a tombstone.

See
[Treating nulls as Unset](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#globally-treating-all-nulls-as-unset)

```
//Setup original data (1, 1, 1) --> (6, 6, 6)
sc.parallelize(1 to 6).map(x => (x, x, x)).saveToCassandra(ks, "tab1")

val ignoreNullsWriteConf = WriteConf.fromSparkConf(sc.getConf).copy(ignoreNulls = true)
//These writes will not delete because we are ignoring nulls
val optRdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 6)
  .map(x => (x, None, None))
  .saveToCassandra(ks, "tab1", writeConf = ignoreNullsWriteConf)

val results = sc.cassandraTable[(Int, Int, Int)](ks, "tab1").collect

results
/**
  (1, 1, 1),
  (2, 2, 2),
  (3, 3, 3),
  (4, 4, 4),
  (5, 5, 5),
  (6, 6, 6)
**/
```

There is also much finer grained controls
[Full Docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#skipping-columns-and-avoiding-tombstones-on-writes-connector-version-16-and-cassandra-22)

Comment: If you want nulls to be treated as unset

Comment: The linked doc for Treating nulls as Unset specifically mentions DataFrames. Does it apply to RDDs as well?

Comment: The document is saying that the parameter is the method for Dataframes because Dataframes cannot use the other methods. The parameter, and all the other examples, work on RDDsl.